# How to access video.play() API on modern Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I am using HTML5 video tag API to play the video from the webcam, like this:

```
videoElement = element.find('video')[0];
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, function(stream) {
 if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  videoElement.mozSrcObject = stream;
 } else {
  var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
 }
videoElement.play();
```

Recently I've started having an error : `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources`.

There was also this feature link - https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4765305641369600 which was about `Deprecate MediaStreamTrack.getSources()` in favor of `MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`. However `MediaStreamTrack.getSources` is `undefined` if I run it from console. Not sure this is related.

While trying to solve this I've found this implementation description - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise?hl=en - which states that now `video.play()` returns a Promise:

```
var playPromise = document.querySelector('video').play();

// In browsers that don’t yet support this functionality,
// playPromise won’t be defined.
if (playPromise !== undefined) {
  playPromise.then(function() {
    // Automatic playback started!
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Automatic playback failed.
    // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback.
  });
}
```

Testing this code always falls in catch section - **Automatic playback failed**.

However this demo work fine for me - https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/play-return-promise/ but it's an `<audio>` tag.

I am using Chrome v.53. In current Firefox the old code works fine however.

Answer (score 1):

To get the right promise you need to wait until video data has been loaded. So

```
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    playPromise = video.play();
});
video.load();
```